# JavaFX CSS - How to curve a border radius outwards?

Tags: javafx, javafx-css, border-radius

I am trying to give a tab the following effect when being selected:

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHuLa.png)

You can see the selected export tab's bottom right corner curving over on top of the other tab.

How could this be implemented using CSS or code?

I have tried utilising the :before and :after pseudo classes, but those are not valid in JavaFX.

Comment: Hi , i have this so far `.tab:selected  {
     -fx-shape: "M0,0 H600, V200  C600,600 600,600 700,600 H0 z";
}
` but i can't figure how to overlap headers

Comment: It's an illusion.